# How do I enter the Konami Code on the PC using a keyboard?

Tags: pc, keyboard, metal-gear-rising-revengeance

I'm trying to do the Konami Code on the PC so I can unlock all the additional difficulties.

I'm entering UP UP DOWN DOWN LEFT RIGHT LEFT RIGHT B A at the start screen, right before it prompts you to choose a savefile, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried instead of using B A, to use the buttons associated with  those on an xbox controller? I think B = use (if you haven't changed it should be f) and A = jump (again if you haven't changed it space). Also maybe trying with the wasd keys

Comment: Yeah I did that and it still doesn't trigger the voice line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Metal_Gear_Rising:_Revengeance#Input_settings

> The Konami Code can only be input with a controller.

However, you can use controller emulation software to send controller input with keyboard (unless the game blocks synthetic events).